# so how to resolve validation exist with one function?

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I have a form to enter the date, where the start date and end date may not be the same as the existing data in the database.
so here my code:

```js
<script>
.........
........
    start: {
                            required: true,
                            date: true,
                            remote: {
                            url: "<?php echo site_url('activity/check_date')?>",
                              type: "post",
                              data: {
                               start: function(){ return $("#date").val(); }

                                         }
                                   }  

                        },
                        end: {
                            required: true,
                            date: true,
                            remote: {
                            url: "<?php echo site_url('activity/check_end')?>",
                              type: "post",
                              data: {
                               end: function(){ return $("#end").val(); }

                                         }
                                   }  
                        },
                       
                    },

                     messages: {
                            start: 
                             {
                                    remote: 'Date already in use.'
                             },
                             end:
                             {
                                remote: 'Date already in use.'
                             },
                      }, 
........
........
</script>
```

```html
<input type="text"  class="form-control"  id="date" name="start" >
<input type="text"  class="form-control" readonly id="end" name="end" required>
```

my model:

```html
public function tanggal($start)
 {
  $nik=$this->session->userdata('nik');

  $this->db->where('start_date', $start);
  $this->db->where('nik',$nik);
  $query = $this->db->get('t_trx_activity');
  if( $query->num_rows() > 0 )
   { 
    return TRUE; 
   } else 
   { 
    return FALSE; 
   }
 }

 public function end_date($end)
 {
  $nik=$this->session->userdata('nik');

  $this->db->where('end_date', $end);
  $this->db->where('nik',$nik);
  $query = $this->db->get('t_trx_activity');
  if( $query->num_rows() > 0 )
   { 
    return TRUE; 
   } else 
   { 
    return FALSE; 
   }
 }
```

my controller:

```html
public function check_date()
 {
  $start=$this->input->post('start');
  $result=$this->activity->tanggal($start);
  if($result)
  {
   echo "false";
  }else{
   echo "true";
  }
 }

 public function check_end()
 {
  $end=$this->input->post('end');
  $result=$this->activity->end_date($end);
  
  if($result)
  {
   echo "false";
  }else{
   echo "true";
  }
 }
```

i think my function in above it's not simple code,i want create model and controller only one function.because start_date and end date in one table.
so how to resolve validation exist with one function?

Answer (score 0):

use a single route pass the type to the model:

model

```
public function check_date_model($type,$val)
    {
        $nik=$this->session->userdata('nik');

        $this->db->where($type, $val);
        $this->db->where('nik',$nik);
        $query = $this->db->get('t_trx_activity');
        if( $query->num_rows() > 0 )
            { 
                return TRUE; 
            } else 
            { 
                return FALSE; 
            }
    }
```

controller

```
public function check_date($type)
    {
        $start=$this->input->post('data');
        $type=$this->input->post('type');
        $result=$this->activity->check_date_model($type,$data);
        if($result)
        {
            echo "false";
        }else{
            echo "true";
        }
    }
```

js:

```
required: true,
                        date: true,
                        remote: {
                        url: "<?php echo site_url('activity/check_date')?>",
                          type: "post",
                          data: {
                           data:$("#date").val(),
                            type:"start_date"
                                     }
                               }  

                    },
                    end: {
                        required: true,
                        date: true,
                        remote: {
                        url: "<?php echo site_url('activity/check_date')?>",
                          type: "post",
                          data: {
                           data: $("#end").val(),
                           type:"end_date"

                                     }
                               }  
                    },
```